# Google Maps -> Setting a marker as draggable, I want to stop it from being draggable later on via client side logic?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So, I know how to plot a marker on the map.

I have an event that occurs once that event occurs on the client side I need to stop the marker from being draggable from that point on.

I thought it might be as simple as this. :

```
marker.setDraggable = false;
```

From what I can see this is not working, I see that it has the setIcon and several other methods, but not seeing how I can stop draggable.

Any advice/suggestions is greatly appreciated.  I have been looking at this for quite some time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Marker has a `setDraggable` method, so you want `marker.setDraggable(false);`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: Sorry, I see what I was doing incorrectly thank you puck.  Will mark as answer shortly.